# I have some questions about a certification

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recieved a document following :

> This is to certify that the name TING CHOE born on 15 December 2000 a citizen of KOREA, SOUTH DOES NOT APPEAR in this Bureau's Hold Departure, Blacklist, Watch list and/or Intelligence Derogatory Records as of 28 February 2017.
>   This certification is issued upon request of **the subject** for **VIMS** Application purposes.

1. Who is *the subject* in the last sentence? Is it me or the officer?
2. What's the meaning of VIMS?

Comment: The subject is TING CHOE (which is you). VIMS looks like an acronym for something you are applying to/for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visa Issuance Made Simpler

*VIMS*

The information in your question suggests you be able able to get expedited visa consideration.